# How can I copy FME format attributes

Tags: fme

I am using FME Workbench 2018.1.0.1 in Windows 10. I am inputting a *kmz* file. The only parameter I am reading from it is PLACEMARK because I see no reason to read the others. I need to copy format attributes *kml_name* and *kml_description* to NAME and CAPACITY, respectively. I don't see in the AttributeCopier transformer where I can do this. Its Import Wizard does not seem to be made to do this.

[image: Import Wizard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to expose them first. Double-click on your feature type (Placemark) and go to the Format Attributes tab. There you can select the format attributes you want to expose so you can use them after in downstream transformers.

[image: Format Attributes]